# Ways of defining accepted template parameter values

Tags: c++, templates, constants, compile-time

My program has a series of functions that take a template argument for an integer that needs to be known at compile time. The functions only accept a few possible values for this integer, and I am looking for a clean way to have a single place defining these options so the list can easily added or changed.  Here is an example of how I am currently doing this.

```
template<int Dim>
float computeMinDist(float* data, int idx);

float computeMinDistSelect(float* data, int idx, int dim) {
    if(dim <= 64) {
        return computeMinDist<64>(data, idx);
    }
    else if(dim <= 100) {
        return computeMinDist<100>(data, idx);
    }
    else {
        printf("Dimension over 100 not supported.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

I have other functions that have the selected dimension parameter, and I would like to be able to define all of the options in one place.  I've tried using a `static constexpr` arrays or `enums` to store the options, but can't get it to compile.  Any advice would be great!  Thanks.

Comment: Male an array of function pointers?  `auto funcs[] = {&computeMinDist<64>, &computeMinDist<100>, ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a table at compile time and binary search it for the specific value you get at runtime:

```
using table_pair = std::pair<int, float(*)(float*, int)>;
template <int... Dims>
constexpr auto make_table() {
    auto arr = std::array<table_pair, sizeof...(Dims)>
    {
        table_pair{Dims, &computeMinDist<Dims>}...
    };
    // Can get rid of this sort if you can guarantee you always pass ordered Dims 
    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [](auto& l, auto& r) {
        return l.first < r.first;
    });
    return arr;
}

// Here you define all possible options.
constexpr auto table = make_table<64, 100>();

float computeMinDistSelect(float* data, int idx, int dim) {
    auto it = std::lower_bound(
        table.begin(), table.end(), 
        table_pair{dim, nullptr}, 
        [](auto& l, auto& r) { return l.first < r.first; });

    if (it == table.end()) {
        printf("Dimension %d not supported.\n", dim);
        exit(1);
    }
    return it->second(data, idx);
}
```

I return an array that we binary search since I assume your values seem to be pretty sparse. If your possible values are pretty dense, you can just return an array of function pointers with the invalid values having `nullptr` and index into the table directly.

https://godbolt.org/z/Yce355bP4